Show all available components in a vuejs project
I am implementing an icon library and I want to create a page listing all available icons.
Every icon is a Vue component and is exported as named export in an index file as such
export { default as FooIcon } from './fooIcon.vue'
How can I get a list of every icon component? I want to display every possible component in a page for the user to know the name of the icon they need to add to their Vue project.
I currently can only add one by one the icons to the page but I want to automate the process

what bundler? in vite/rollup you can import.meta.glob and generate a file

@AlexanderNenashev I use both, Vite for dev and rollup for buiding. It looks like it could do the trick!

i guess you should use a rollup hook to generate your file manually.

@AlexanderNenashev I hoped to use it directly to a view.vue. so, you are proposing to generate a Vue file as a build step?

yes, you cannot dynamically export named exports, the imports/exports are static
